# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y.pickle'

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I am following [this code tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/using-trained-model-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/) - How to use your trained model - Deep Learning basics with Python, TensorFlow and Keras.

Below is the code I am using:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

X = X/255.0


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer="Adam",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

I've encountered the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8560275e4263> in <module>
      6 
      7 X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
----> 8 y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))
      9 
     10 X = X/255.0

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'y.pickle'
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `"X.pickle"` at that location?

Comment: This code is from the tutorial: How to use your trained model - Deep Learning basics with Python, TensorFlow and Keras p.6.

You have to follow the previous videos in the series for this code to be functional.

Comment: Are your files in the same directory as your .py?